# Symfony2: Session Global variable in PHP template

Tags: php, templates, session, symfony

Symfony doc says:

> During each request, Symfony2 will set a global template variable app
>   in both Twig and PHP template engines by default. The app variable is
>   a GlobalVariables instance which will give you access to some
>   application specific variables automatically:
>  app.security - The
>   security context.
>  app.user - The current user object.
>   app.request - The request object.
>  app.session - The session
>   object.
>  app.environment - The current environment (dev, prod,
>   etc).
>  app.debug - True if in debug mode. False otherwise.

Examples:
In twig: `{{ app.request.method }}` 
In PHP: `echo $app->getRequest()->getMethod()`
In twig: `{{ app.user.username }}` 
But for the session object:
In twig: `{{ app.session.varname }}`
In PHP: `// I don't know, do you know how to call it?`
I've tried: `$session = $app->getSession('uid');` but when I try to store it to a database it tells me:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session could not be converted to
>   string in C:\wamp\www...

There's a lack of resources when it comes to PHP templates, but in my case I can't switch for some reasons.

The question in other words, what is the equivalent in PHP templating of:
`{{ app.session.varname }}`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In twig: `{{ app.session.varname }}`

In PHP: `echo $app->getSession()->get('uid');`

Comment: Hey are you kinda mocking me? :) Great guy, that did it, thanks a ton for your answer.

Comment: No mocking intended.  I had your question commented out and positioned to make it clear as to which problem was being addresses.  Then @Daniel Ribereiro went in and edited stuff.  No idea why but it messed the intent up.

Comment: You're using .varname in twig and then get('uid') in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
$session = $this->get('session');

if ($session->has('varname')) {
    echo $session->varname
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that works either in a page.html.php template? It gives me this err: `Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\SessionHelper::$uid in C:\wamp\www\...` I'm already using your code in the Default Controller for each controller and render the session value, the thing I'm trying to avoid by my question here, I need to use a global variable as the Symfony2 docs says above.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to error_log $app->getSession() to see what it returns?

```
error_log(var_dump($app->getSession(), true));
```